# Boostrap theme still return jQuery old version error even newest version is used

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I have install Drupal 7 in my local web-server, and got problem with Bootstrap theme.
I install Bootstrap theme 3.x for Drupal 7.x, jQuery Update is installed and configured to use the jQuery version 1.10 with Google CDN, I created a sub-theme from Bootstrap as base theme.

But when I go to status report in drupal administrative page, there is a line: 
"**Bootstrap verion jQuery 1.10.2..**"
but on the next line, it still return the warning message:
"**Bootstrap requires jQuery 1.7 or greater. Configure jQuery Update.**"
and marked with red cross. (even I cleared the cache).

I did some research but was unable to find anything that matches my problem.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: A weird problem... What I would do, the best way to find the error, is to check the code of the bootstrap module to see why you are getting the warning message. If you are on localhost is even easier to debug, even step by step.

Comment: Oh, I change the version of jQuery for administrative to 1.7 or 1.8 then the warning gone.
But if I use the 1.10 it appear again.
May be there are some bugs in Bootstrap base theme source code? (I don't touch anything there). Hix..

Comment: Usually the error is between the chair and the PC (we are the error usually :) ).Check the code to see what's happening, and if there's a bug, then open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but as there is no correct answer provided and for the sake of completeness here is a patch that solves this problem:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2244553#comment-9722659

(How to apply patches: https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply)